# Object recognition with stereoscopic vision

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, gesture-recognition, stereoscopy

I'm creating a static gesture recognition system using an OpenCV Haar Cascade Classifier.  I ultimately would like to turn this recognition system into a stereoscopic recognition system.  Here is my question, can I take the 2D recognition system created by the Haar Cascade Classifier and implement it on both cameras in order to create a disparity map after using the stereoscopic calibration functions contained in OpenCV? Or, would I have to take pictures with my already calibrated stereoscopic system to create the cascade classifier?

It's hard to find good information on this topic, and I would like to plan my project and make sure I'm doing the correct things before buying and creating everything.

Thanks.

Comment: there's no such thing as a 'stereoscopic cascade classifier'. yet the idea of taking 2 cropped images (from a CascadeClassifier) and making a 3d/disparity image from that sounds pretty reasonable to me.

Comment: it all boils down to restricting the disparity image generation to the detected regions from the CascadeClassifier, no ?

Comment: Right.  I'm assuming by taking the offset of the two detected regions I can detect disparity, thus allowing me to calculate distance to the object.

Comment: oh, you're not talking about making a disparity image by blockmatching or such ?

Comment: I'm not necessarily sure.  I would like to use the built in stereoscopy functions because they are very sound and tested, I'm just trying to figure out a way to implement my gesture recognition in order to find the angle and distance of an object.  I'm now thinking this might be easier using blockmatching.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should clarify what it is you are trying to accomplish.

Do you need to detect an object and then localize it in 3D world coordinates? Or do you need the 3D information in order to detect the object in the first place?

In the former case, there are a couple of ways to go.  One is to calibrate your stereo camera system, detect the object in both cameras, and then find its 3D location by triangulation. For example, you may want to triangulate the centroid of the object. The problem with this approach is that the 2D localization of the cascade object detector may not be precise enough to get a reliable 3D point.

The other way is to calibrate your cameras, and then to rectify the images to make them look as though the cameras are parallel and row-aligned. Now instead of triangulating specific points, you can compute disparity map for the whole image and get a corresponding 3D location (in theory) for any pixel. Now you can detect your object of interest in camera 1, and then use the disparity map to find a 3D location of any point on the object.

On the other hand, if you want to use 3D information to improve your detection, you will have to read up on some very recent research.  For example, here is a paper on [people detection using RGB-D sensors](http://www.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/~spinello/spinelloIROS11.pdf). The paper talks about the HOD (Histogram of Oriented Depths) descriptor, as opposed to the HOG descriptor.  The reason this is relevant, is that if you calibrate your cameras and rectify your images you can get the same kind of depth map that you get from an RGB-D sensor like Kinect.